# What is the origin of Biz Markie's stage name?

Tags: rap, hip-hop, names

Did the rapper Biz Markie get his name from the Prussian statesman Otto von Bismarck? According to the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biz_Markie#Leben_und_Wirken), it is either this, or the baseballer Biz Mackey, but it gives no source. Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some sources, that seem to have all copied themselves (e.g. [here](http://www.amworldgroup.com/artist-booking/biz-markie) or [there](https://app.discotech.me/artists/biz-markie/)) say:

> Born **Marcel** Hall in Harlem USA, Biz Markie stepped onto the scene in 1985, at age fourteen, as the beat box backup for Roxanne Shanté of the “Juice Crew.” He then adopted his alias–**“Biz” a name his mother used to call him because he was such a busybody** and **“Markie,” short for Marcel**, was his neighborhood nickname.